# Removing character spacing

Tags: vba, fonts, powerpoint

I'm trying to remove the character spacing (i.e. normal, not condensed or expanded) from all text in PowerPoint slides.

I know the following code but could not find the proper object of textFrame.

```
With ActivePresentation 
For Each oSl In .Slides 
For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes 
With oSh If .HasTextFrame 
Then If .TextFrame.HasText 
Then .TextFrame.TextRange.?? = normal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of .TextFrame, use .TextFrame2, like so:

```
.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font.Spacing = 0
```